# How to print the information of mem_map using proc file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to print virtual address of mem_map,physical address of mem_map and the number of struct page now.
so I tried running code of [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236757/print-virtual-address-of-mem-map-using-a-proc-file),but it seemed like it didn't show correct address.
Could you tell me how I can fix this?

Below is the result of execution.

mem_map virt addr:           (null) 
mem_map phys addr: 131941395333120 
mem_map phys pages: 18446744072101367984

I'm using Ubuntu12.04(64bit) and kernel version is 3.13.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

#include <asm/switch_to.h>
#include <linux/types.h> /* size_t */
#include <linux/fcntl.h> /* O_ACCMODE */
#include <asm/uaccess.h> /* copy_from/to_user */
#include <linux/fs.h>       // for basic filesystem
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>  // for the proc filesystem
#include <linux/seq_file.h> // for sequence files
#include <linux/mm.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static struct proc_dir_entry* proc_file;
struct page *mem_map;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(mem_map);

/* memory map functions */
int mem_map_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v);
//virtual_to_physical
inline unsigned long virt_to_phy(unsigned long addr);

inline unsigned long virt_to_phy(unsigned long addr){
    return __pa(addr);
}

char buf[300];

int mem_map_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v){

    int ret_val = 0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Proc file read \n");
    ret_val =  seq_printf(m, "mem_map virt addr: %p \n", mem_map);
    ret_val += seq_printf(m, "mem_map phys addr: %lu \n",virt_to_phy((unsigned long)mem_map));
    ret_val += seq_printf(m, "mem_map phys pages: %lu \n", (long unsigned int)get_num_physpages);
    return ret_val;
}

static int mem_map_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file){
    return single_open(file, mem_map_show, NULL);
}

struct file_operations mem_map_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = mem_map_open,
    .read = seq_read,
    .llseek = seq_lseek,
    .release = single_release,
};

static int __init mem_map_init(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loaded mem_map module\n");
    proc_file = proc_create("mem_map", 0, NULL, &mem_map_fops);
    if(!proc_file){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error: Could not initialize /proc/mem_map");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }   
    return 0;
}

static void __exit mem_map_exit(void){
    remove_proc_entry("mem_map",NULL);  
    printk(KERN_INFO "Proc file unloaded \n");
}


/* Declaration of the init and exit functions */
module_init(mem_map_init);
module_exit(mem_map_exit);
```

Comment: You declare a variable `mem_map` that is a pointer, and even exports its' symbol, but where do you actually initialize it? What is it exactly that you want to print, the address of what?

Comment: I thought mem_map was initialized in somewhere.because according to the article that I saw, mem_map wasn't assigned by anything.That's why I was confused. but your point is very obvious.Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to print the address of the *global* `mem_map` array, right from your kernel module. The pointer that you're looking for is global ,therefore [it has already been exported](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.13/source/mm/memory.c#L82) for you to use in your kernel module. All you have to do is find its' symbol.

Finding an exported symbol is easy, by including `<linux/kallsyms.h>` you'll have the power of using `kallsyms_lookup_name()` which takes a `char *` and returns the address of the symbol it represents. All you have to do now, is assigning the address to the empty pointer, possibly in your `init` function.

```
mem_map = (struct page *) kallsyms_lookup_name("mem_map");
```

Now your `mem_map` pointer actually points to the `mem_map` array that you're after. Cool.

Next, you're declaring `virt_to_phy()` and using `__pa()` inside it. Why? You can simply use `virt_to_phys()` that is already declared (and doing exactly the same in your case) in `asm/io.h`. Please not that you're trying to print an address, therefore the right `printf` format would be `%lx` instead of `%lu`.

Last but not least, ridiculous the number of pages you're examining is actually the decimal value of the address of `get_num_physpages`, which is a function. If you wish to print the return value of `get_num_physpages` you should call it as a function, `get_num_physpages()` because now your code prints the value of the pointer to `get_num_physpages`.

This is how I think your code should have looked like:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <asm/io.h>

#define ERROR -1

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static struct proc_dir_entry* proc_file;
struct page *mem_map;

int mem_map_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v)
{
    int ret_val = 0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Proc file read\n");
    ret_val =  seq_printf(m, "mem_map virt addr:\t0x%p\n", mem_map);
    ret_val += seq_printf(m, "mem_map phys addr:\t0x%016llx\n", ((unsigned long long) virt_to_phys((volatile void *) mem_map)));
    ret_val += seq_printf(m, "mem_map phys pages:\t%lu\n", (long unsigned int) get_num_physpages());
    return ret_val;
}

static int mem_map_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    return single_open(file, mem_map_show, NULL);
}

struct file_operations mem_map_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = mem_map_open,
    .read = seq_read,
    .llseek = seq_lseek,
    .release = single_release,
};

static int __init mem_map_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loaded mem_map module\n");
    mem_map = (struct page *) kallsyms_lookup_name("mem_map");
    if (!mem_map) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error: Unable to find address of global 'mem_map'\n");
                return ERROR;
        }
    proc_file = proc_create("mem_map", 0, NULL, &mem_map_fops);
    if (!proc_file) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error: Could not initialize /proc/mem_map\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit mem_map_exit(void)
{
    remove_proc_entry("mem_map",NULL);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Proc file unloaded\n");
}


/* Declaration of the init and exit functions */
module_init(mem_map_init);
module_exit(mem_map_exit);
```

and more specifically, if you want to comply with how values in `procfs` are printed, I would implement `mem_map_show` somewhat like this:

```
int mem_map_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v)
{
    int ret_val = 0;

    ret_val =  seq_printf(m, "0x%p 0x%016llx %lu\n",
            mem_map, 
            ((unsigned long long) virt_to_phys((volatile void *) mem_map)),
            (long unsigned int) get_num_physpages());
    return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: It completely works for me. What you said makes sence. I really appreciate it.Whenever I find the answer about Linux, I can't find it. Could you recommend any site or books for Linux kernel programming if possible?

Comment: sure, in my opinion these 3 books are essential, ["Linux Kernel Development", Robert Love](https://www.amazon.com/Linux-Kernel-Development-Robert-Love/dp/0672329468), ["Linux Device Drivers",  Jonathan Corbet](https://www.amazon.com/Linux-Device-Drivers-Jonathan-Corbet/dp/0596005903/) and ["Understanding the Linux Kernel", Daniel P. Bovet](https://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Linux-Kernel-Third-Daniel/dp/0596005652). In addition, read and _understand_ the code. Make use of [LXR](http://lxr.free-electrons.com).

Comment: i have minor concerns here. 1) what's up with ERROR of -1 2) the mem_map symbol can end up aliasing the global one. in fact chances are kallsyms_lookup already returns that instead of the expected one. i also have to note the entire assignment looks super fishy.

Comment: actually i take that back. this mem_map business was bugging me a lot and I'm reasonably confident the kernel at hand does not have the symbol in the first place and indeed kallsyms returns your own local symbol instead. looks like someone in the another SO thread found the mm/memory.c snippet but they misread the ifdef. CONFIG_NEED_MULTIPLE_NODES is set by default and that implies mem_map is NOT present to begin with.